# Prove or disprove a matrix logarithm equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $\Bbb{S}_{++}^n$ denote the space of symmetric positive definite (SPD) $n\times n$ real matrices, and let $A,B\in\Bbb{S}_{++}^n$.

Is it possible to express the logarithm of $A^{-1}B$ as a difference of the form $P-Q$, where $P,Q$ are $n\times n$ real matrices, not necessarily SPD, but P must depend solely on $A$ and $Q$ must depend solely on $B$, i.e.,
$$
\log(A^{-1}B)=P-Q.
$$

Note that, in genral, $AB\neq BA$.

**EDIT:** This question is a part of a more general [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1334670/show-the-negative-definiteness-of-a-squared-riemannian-metric) I asked on MathSE. I am not sure that this is the right approach for attacking my original problem, but I am interested in this one in any case.

Comment: Have you done some numerical experiments? In particular, testing longer chains such as $(P-Q)+(Q-R)+(R-S)=(P-S)$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @FedericoPoloni. No, the truth is that I did not. But how could do that. I cannot figure out how the logarithm should be treated.

Comment: What do you mean by "treated"? Matlab, Mathematica and Python (sympy) all have library functions to compute matrix logarithms without trouble.

Comment: I am not a differential geometer, but after reading the formulation in your other question, I am more convinced that it can't be done, at least with a reasonably smooth function. What you ask for is a distance-preserving isomorphism between $\mathbb{S}^n_+$ and $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$, and this shouldn't be possible because they have different curvature.

Comment: Well, what I would like to find is a relation between $P$, $Q$ and $A$, $B$, respectively. I am not interested in a numerical solution.
So, concerning my question on MathSE, you believe that the squared distance $d^2$ I give is not negative-definite?

Comment: The Riemannian distance is not negative definite; that is, $\exp(-\gamma d^2(X,Y))$ is **not** a positive definite function.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Suvrit. This is what I have come up with too. I have found that instead of this affine-invariant geodesic distance, I should use the Log-Euclidean distance ($\lVert \log(A)-\log(B)\rVert_{F}$) such that the constructed kernel to be positive-definite. Are you familiarized with this one?

Comment: Well, Mr. @Suvrit, apparently you are familiarized with all this theory. In the last few day, I have read many of your papers. By the way, congratulations for this magnificent work! I hope I'll have the opportunity to cite some of your papers in the foreseeable future!

Comment: Here is a link to a paper that answers your "kernel" question in complete detail (the log-Euclidean transform indeed leads to a kernel but at the expense of "killing" the curvature):  http://www2.compute.dtu.dk/~sohau/papers/cvpr2015/feragen_cvpr2015.pdf

Comment: That's what I was studying right now. It's straight to the point, really good work I think. I believe that killing the curvature is not a problem in my case. Apropos, would you mind suggesting me a good introductory book for beginning studying Riemannian Geometry? Thank you very much again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution is inspired by the comment of Federico Poloni. Suppose there exist such functions, i.e. $$log(A^{-1}B)=P(A)-Q(B).$$ for all SPD-matrices $A,B$. Putting $A=B$ yields $P(A)=Q(A)$ for all SPD-matrix $A$. Now if the equation above holds we would have $$log(A^{-1}B)+log(B^{-1}C)+log(C^{-1}A)=0.$$
However simply choosing random matrices shows that this indentity does not hold. Here is a matlab code:
d=2;

A=gen_rand_spd(d);

B=gen_rand_spd(d);

C=gen_rand_spd(d);

logm(A^(-1)*B)+logm(B^(-1)*C)+logm(C^(-1)*A)

function [A] = gen_rand_spd(d)

A=rand(d);

A=A+A';

A=expm(A);

end

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Well, that's clear. Would you mind take a look at my original question at MathSE? I'm interested in showing that the squared distance $d^2$ is negative definite. $d$ in my case is a geodesic metric between SPD matrices in $\Bbb{S}_{++}^n$. Is this something possible to be shown? Thanks once again!
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1334670/show-the-negative-definiteness-of-a-squared-riemannian-metric

Comment: I read the question on MathSE but to be honest I didn't understand it. What do you mean by negative definite? By the way you gave the definition of the metric induced by the Riemannian metric and not the Riemannian metric itself. Also I dont understand why the metric could also be defined as $||log(A^{-1}B)||_F$.

Comment: To tell the truth, I am not familiarized with this theory, that's why I am here! I gave that metric because that was proposed by Förstner and Moonen. If you want take a look to the paper I give below (Eq.13). I need to use a distance metric to measure the similarity between two SPD matrices (but not the Log-Euclidean one). So, I came up with this one, which also seems to work properly in my case. However, I would like to show that I could use this distance to construct a PD kernel $k(\cdot,\cdot)=\exp(-\gamma d^2(\cdot,\cdot))$, and that's why I need $d^2$ to be negative-definite, ...>

Comment: ... just like the square Euclidean distance (which is negative-definite). Would you like to suggest my some other approach maybe? What would be the metric you mention above?

Comment: Well, I forgot to give the link of the paper: http://www.ipb.uni-bonn.de/fileadmin/publication/pdf/Forstner1999Metric.pdf

Comment: I still dont know what you mean by negative-definite in your case. But maybe it is related to the non-positive curvature of SPD(n), see Page 314 and following of http://www.math.bgu.ac.il/~barakw/rigidity/bh.pdf

Comment: I mean that in the sense of the definition I give. That is, if $f\colon\mathcal{X}\times\mathcal{X}\to\Bbb{R}$ it is negative-definite if it satisfies the conditions I give (and I was given!) in the definition. In our case now, $\mathcal{X}\equiv\Bbb{S}_{++}^n$...

Comment: I am sorry I was confused because you wrote "It suffices to show that..." so I thought its not a definition. Experiments with Matlab suggest that the squared distance function is not negative-definite. Here is the code I used:d=2;
n=20;
A=zeros(d,d,n);
for i=1:n
    A(:,:,i)=gen_rand_spd(d);
end

M=zeros(n);
for i=1:n
    for j=1:n
        M(i,j)=dist2spd(A(:,:,i),A(:,:,j));
    end
end

T=[ones(1,n-1);-eye(n-1)];
M=T'*M*T;
sort(eig(M))

Comment: Here the function dist2spd: function [d] = dist2spd(A,B)
%square of the distance
Asqr=sqrtm(A);
lABA=logm(Asqr\B/Asqr);
d=sum(sum(lABA.^2));
end

Comment: Well, I need to check this, cause it's a bit tricky... On the other hand, by using this distance, along with a Mahalanobis-like one, I get PD kernels, so it confuses me. Do you believe that this squared distance, along with the squared Mahalanobis 
$$
(x-x_i)^\top\Big(\frac{A+B}{2}\Big)(x-x_i),
$$
which is defined jointly on $\Bbb{R}^n\times\Bbb{S}_{++}^n$ could be negative-definite as a sum?

Comment: Sorry, but I can not follow. Can you clarify your question.

Comment: You're right... Well, what I was saying is that I have tried a kernel of the form 
$$
\exp(-\gamma f((x_i,\Sigma_i),(x_j,\Sigma_j))),
$$,
where 
$$
f((x_i,\Sigma_i),(x_j,\Sigma_j))=(x-x_i)^\top(\frac{\Sigma_i+\Sigma_j}{2})^{-1}(x-x_i) + d^2(\Sigma_i,\Sigma_j),
$$
and it seems to be ok (PD), so I deduce that $f$ is negative-definite (there is a theorem for this). I would like to prove that, as well. As for the squared Mahalanobis term (first term of $f$ above), I have shown that it's ND... That's why I am really confused...

Comment: I suppose you mean $x_j-x_i$ instead of $x-x_i$. I don't think that $f$ is negative-definite. If $x_i=x_j$ for all $(i,j)$ the first term drops and only the second terms remains which does not seem to be negative-definite.

Comment: Yes that's what I mean: $x_i-x_j$. So, this seems weird. Your comment seems reasonable, but the kernel I construct using $f$ seems to work as PD. I'll try to figure it out, many thanks for your help!

Comment: Well in my experiments, sometimes it was negative-definite and sometimes not. Most eigenvalues are negative. Also positive eigenvalues only occured if n was large enough (about n>10).

Comment: Then, something is wrong here... Note that my $d^2$ is computed as follows:
$$
d^2(\Sigma_i,\Sigma_j) = \sum_{t=1}^{n} \log^2(\lambda_t),
$$
where $\lambda_t$ denotes the $t$-th eigenvalue of the generalized eigenvalue problem (GEP): $\Sigma_iU=\Lambda\Sigma_jU$... This is because of Eq.(14) here: http://www.ipb.uni-bonn.de/fileadmin/publication/pdf/Forstner1999Metric.pdf

Comment: I used the direct formula for the metric.

Comment: You mean $\lVert\log(\Sigma_i^{-1}\Sigma_j)\rVert^2_{F}$?

Comment: No $\|\text{log}(\sum_i^{-1/2}\sum_j\sum_i^{-1/2})\|_F^2$, but I also tried your formula with the same result.